# Have DataGridView Not Be Filtered On Form Load

Tags: c#

I am adding a combo-box to the top of my windows form to allow the user to filter the datagridview on the selection.  This works, but my issue is that when the windows form loads, I want it to by default show all selections and only show a filtered list if the user selects an option from the drop down.

How should I alter  this code so that when the windows form loads ALL options are displayed and not an empty filtered list?

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class TestCheck : Form
    {
        public TestCheck()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestCheck_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnSaveEdits.Visible = false;

            AddStores();
            btnSaveEdits.Visible = true;
            dgvTest.DataSource = StartupForm.dtTestC;
            dgvTest.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
            dgvTest.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
            dgvTest.AutoResizeColumns();

        }

        private void cboStores_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dv = StartupForm.dtTestC.DefaultView;
            var combotext = cboStores.Text;
            combotext = combotext.Trim().Replace("'", "''");
            if (combotext == "All")
            {
                dv.RowFilter = "";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Location  LIKE '%{0}%'", combotext);
                cboStores.DataSource = dv;
            }
        }

        private void AddStores()
        {
            DataRow dr;
            DataTable dt;
            dt = StartupForm.dtTestC.Copy();
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { "--Select A Store--" };
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            cboStores.ValueMember = "Location";
            cboStores.DisplayMember = "Location";
            cboStores.DataSource = dt;
        }
}
```

**EDIT**
This is all intellisense gives me...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because comboBox returns position -1 when form loads that is equal to null or empty. Try to create like this

```
string value = comboBox.selecTedItem.toString();

if(value.Equals("") || value.Equals("All"){
//add you code here to load the data to your table
}
```

Comment: this goes in the Form_Load() event?

Comment: yes, Your correct. Just update me if there's something wrong. Please check i just edited my solution `&&` changes to `||`

Comment: I get a compile error of object does not contain a definition for Value on the string value.... line

Comment: see my image.  it's not letting me select value from SelectedItem

Comment: I mean comboBox.selecTedItem.toString();

Comment: That gives me a debug error of `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` on the string value.... line

Comment: what about cboStores.Text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198701/discussion-between-cyrille-con-morales-and-douglove).